# convert c# to javascript for Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

i have a class called crafting blueprints that has one constructor im trying to add items to a database in another script but i cannot figure out how to convert some c# script to unityscript, help would be great appreciated,

```
blueprints.Add(CraftingBlueprints(
  "Wood Pole", 
  List.<int>(new int[]{0}), 
  List.<int>(new int[]{3}), 
  itemDatabase.itemsDatabase[5]));
```

`List.<int>(new int[]{0})` is the part I'm having trouble converting.

Comment: what do you mean by "unityscript"? do you mean C# (CSharp)?

Comment: unity script is javascript, just also called unityscript inside unity ans yes C(Sharp)

Comment: that's not valid C#, so i'm not sure what you're trying to do. Show what you have in C# and what you've come up with in JS so far.

Comment: the code comes from a tutorial im watching, its valid code for him, blueprints is a list of a class called CraftingBlueprints, so I'm trying to add an instance of the class by calling the constructor, the constructor consists of two lists containing int's, I'm trying to add items to the lists within the line of code, the tutorial achieves this using the code posted above, i just want to convert that one part to javascript, the rest is done already

Comment: You can have both javascript scripts and C# scripts in unity, can't you?

Comment: yeah, my entire project so far is in javascript though, so id like to figure it out just to keep it simple

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.m2h.nl/files/js_to_c.php) tool solves your problem.I know u.s.(j.s.) to c# , maybe it shows you way.

Comment: I dont understand you have list which has int, but you want to add int array to this list. If you want to hold int array use direct int in list. if you want to use only int array (which means you know the lenght of the int array before initialization.)